# Catching API response for insufficient funds from Stripe

Tags: python, stripe-payments

If I create a Charge object via the Stripe API and the card is valid, but the charge is declined, what error does this cause? It doesn't look to be possible to simulate this error in the test sandbox and I'd like to be able to catch it (and mock it in tests), but the documentation isn't clear on this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would trigger a declined charge which is a `card_error` and can be triggered with this card number: `4000000000000002: Charge will be declined with a card_declined code.`

Comment: Thanks for that. It looks like I overlooked the testing section of the Stripe documentation at https://stripe.com/docs/testing where all the specific response card numbers are mentioned, which is a little frustrating as that looks like a very useful resource